# UI Questions -- where do they fit?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Say you have a question about a UI design.  Does this fit on SuperUser or StackOverflow or neither?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They fit to neither sites. Doctype.com has some design but that is based on web design.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Say you asked:

> I have  a Windows list box with
>   multiple columns and I'd like the
>   second column to be coloured red -
>   what Windows messages do I need to
>   send to implement this?

then I would say that this is suitable for SO, as it is about Windows programming. OTOH

> Please give me some ideas for a UI
>   which would allow me to select an
>   image and associate some text with it.

would not be suitable for SO as (vagueness apart) it isn't about programming.